# createuser: ошибка: не удалось подключиться к базе template1: ВАЖНО: пользователь "damir" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)

Tags: postgresql, cmd

Пытаюсь создать нового пользователя Postgres командой createuser -dlPRS dvdice сначала просит пароль для новой роли и просит его повторить, а потом 2 раза просто какой то "Пароль:" (damir - имя пользователя ПК). Перепробовал все пароли, которые приходят на ум: от системы, от постгреса и тд.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что все-таки за пароль меня спрашивает?